# How to make JQuery stepper/spinner button go faster through list on press down?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, css

I'm working on a stepper/spinner that turns a standard HTML Select list into a spinner where you press + to go up and - to go down.  Have it working OK...

https://jsfiddle.net/5pmarmov/40/

But if you press + or - with your mouse and hold, I'd like it to flip through the list faster, rather than have to actually click once for each step of the list.

Is this possible?  If so, could someone point me in right direction?

Might not matter at this point but just an FYI that I'd like it to work in iOS and Android as well.  Not sure if that's done separately or if same code for desktop will carry over and work on all mobile too (ideal scenario, obviously haha).

Code...
HTML

```
 <select name='weight' id='weightpicker' class='hide-cat-input select-step' >
                        <option value=''>Choose Weight</option>
                        <option value='5'>0 lbs or less</option><option value='5.0625'>5 lbs, 1 oz.</option><option value='5.125'>5 lbs, 2 oz.</option><option value='5.1875'>5 lbs, 3 oz.</option><option value='5.25'>5 lbs, 4 oz.</option><option value='5.3125'>5 lbs, 5 oz.</option><option value='5.375'>5 lbs, 6 oz.</option><option value='5.4375'>5 lbs, 7 oz.</option><option value='5.5'>5 lbs, 8 oz.</option><option value='5.5625'>5 lbs, 9 oz.</option><option value='5.625'>5 lbs, 10 oz.</option><option value='5.6875'>5 lbs, 11 oz.</option><option value='5.75'>5 lbs, 12 oz.</option><option value='5.8125'>5 lbs, 13 oz.</option><option value='5.875'>5 lbs, 14 oz.</option><option value='5.9375'>5 lbs, 15 oz.</option><option value='6'>6 lbs, 0 oz.</option><option value='6.0625'>6 lbs, 1 oz.</option><option value='6.125'>6 lbs, 2 oz.</option><option value='6.1875'>6 lbs, 3 oz.</option><option value='6.25'>6 lbs, 4 oz.</option><option value='6.3125'>6 lbs, 5 oz.</option><option value='6.375'>6 lbs, 6 oz.</option><option value='6.4375'>6 lbs, 7 oz.</option><option value='6.5'>6 lbs, 8 oz.</option><option value='6.5625'>6 lbs, 9 oz.</option><option value='6.625'>6 lbs, 10 oz.</option><option value='6.6875'>6 lbs, 11 oz.</option><option value='6.75'>6 lbs, 12 oz.</option><option value='6.8125'>6 lbs, 13 oz.</option><option value='6.875'>6 lbs, 14 oz.</option><option value='6.9375'>6 lbs, 15 oz.</option><option value='7'>7 lbs, 0 oz.</option><option value='7.0625'>7 lbs, 1 oz.</option><option value='7.125'>7 lbs, 2 oz.</option><option value='7.1875'>7 lbs, 3 oz.</option><option value='7.25'>7 lbs, 4 oz.</option><option value='7.3125'>7 lbs, 5 oz.</option><option value='7.375'>7 lbs, 6 oz.</option><option value='7.4375'>7 lbs, 7 oz.</option><option value='7.5' selected='selected'>7 lbs, 8 oz.</option><option value='7.5625'>7 lbs, 9 oz.</option><option value='7.625'>7 lbs, 10 oz.</option><option value='7.6875'>7 lbs, 11 oz.</option><option value='7.75'>7 lbs, 12 oz.</option><option value='7.8125'>7 lbs, 13 oz.</option><option value='7.875'>7 lbs, 14 oz.</option><option value='7.9375'>7 lbs, 15 oz.</option><option value='8'>8 lbs, 0 oz.</option><option value='8.0625'>8 lbs, 1 oz.</option><option value='8.125'>8 lbs, 2 oz.</option><option value='8.1875'>8 lbs, 3 oz.</option><option value='8.25'>8 lbs, 4 oz.</option><option value='8.3125'>8 lbs, 5 oz.</option><option value='8.375'>8 lbs, 6 oz.</option><option value='8.4375'>8 lbs, 7 oz.</option><option value='8.5'>8 lbs, 8 oz.</option><option value='8.5625'>8 lbs, 9 oz.</option><option value='8.625'>8 lbs, 10 oz.</option><option value='8.6875'>8 lbs, 11 oz.</option><option value='8.75'>8 lbs, 12 oz.</option><option value='8.8125'>8 lbs, 13 oz.</option><option value='8.875'>8 lbs, 14 oz.</option><option value='8.9375'>8 lbs, 15 oz.</option><option value='9'>9 lbs, 0 oz.</option><option value='9.0625'>9 lbs, 1 oz.</option><option value='9.125'>9 lbs, 2 oz.</option><option value='9.1875'>9 lbs, 3 oz.</option><option value='9.25'>9 lbs, 4 oz.</option><option value='9.3125'>9 lbs, 5 oz.</option><option value='9.375'>9 lbs, 6 oz.</option><option value='9.4375'>9 lbs, 7 oz.</option><option value='9.5'>9 lbs, 8 oz.</option><option value='9.5625'>9 lbs, 9 oz.</option><option value='9.625'>9 lbs, 10 oz.</option><option value='9.6875'>9 lbs, 11 oz.</option><option value='9.75'>9 lbs, 12 oz.</option><option value='9.8125'>9 lbs, 13 oz.</option><option value='9.875'>9 lbs, 14 oz.</option><option value='9.9375'>9 lbs, 15 oz.</option><option value='10'>10 lbs, 0 oz.</option><option value='10.0625'>10 lbs, 1 oz.</option><option value='10.125'>10 lbs, 2 oz.</option><option value='10.1875'>10 lbs, 3 oz.</option><option value='10.25'>10 lbs, 4 oz.</option><option value='10.3125'>10 lbs, 5 oz.</option><option value='10.375'>10 lbs, 6 oz.</option><option value='10.4375'>10 lbs, 7 oz.</option><option value='10.5'>10 lbs, 8 oz.</option><option value='10.5625'>10 lbs, 9 oz.</option><option value='10.625'>10 lbs, 10 oz.</option><option value='10.6875'>10 lbs, 11 oz.</option><option value='10.75'>10 lbs, 12 oz.</option><option value='10.8125'>10 lbs, 13 oz.</option><option value='10.875'>10 lbs, 14 oz.</option><option value='10.9375'>10 lbs, 15 oz.</option><option value='11'>11 lbs, 0 oz.</option><option value='11.0625'>11 lbs, 1 oz.</option><option value='11.125'>11 lbs, 2 oz.</option><option value='11.1875'>11 lbs, 3 oz.</option><option value='11.25'>11 lbs, 4 oz.</option><option value='11.3125'>11 lbs, 5 oz.</option><option value='11.375'>11 lbs, 6 oz.</option><option value='11.4375'>11 lbs, 7 oz.</option><option value='11.5'>11 lbs, 8 oz.</option><option value='11.5625'>11 lbs, 9 oz.</option><option value='11.625'>11 lbs, 10 oz.</option><option value='11.6875'>11 lbs, 11 oz.</option><option value='11.75'>11 lbs, 12 oz.</option><option value='11.8125'>11 lbs, 13 oz.</option><option value='11.875'>11 lbs, 14 oz.</option><option value='11.9375'>11 lbs, 15 oz.</option><option value='12'>12 lbs or more</option>
                        </select>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".select-step").selectStep({
          onChange: function(value) {
            console.log(value, "value");
          }
        });
    })
(function ($) {
    $.fn.selectStep = function (vars) {
        /*
         * Function to get all plugin's variables
         * and element options on array
         */
        function getData(element, callback) {
            // Define default variables
            var defaultVars = {
                onChange: null,
                incrementLabel: "+",
                decrementLabel: "-"
            };
            var assign = Object.assign;
            // Get all plugin variables
            vars = assign({}, defaultVars, vars);
            var options = [];
            // Get select options
            var optElement = $(element).find("option");
            optElement.each(function (i, o) {
                var name = $(this).text();
                var value = $(this).attr("value");
                var selected = $(this).is(':selected');
                options = options.concat([{ name: name, value: value, selected: selected }]);
                if (i === optElement.length - 1) {
                    // Fire callback with select options and variables
                    callback(vars, options);
                }
            });
        }
        /*
         * Function to create fake element
         * to mock the select elements
         */
        function addFakeElements(element, callback) {
            getData(element, function (vars, options) {
                // Check if options is empty
                if (!options.length) {
                    return;
                }
                // Add class to select element
                jQuery(element).addClass("select-step");
                // Add fake elements
                var incrementLabel = vars.incrementLabel, decrementLabel = vars.decrementLabel;
                // Find selected option on the select element
                var isSelected = [];
                options.map(function (opt, key) {
                    if (opt.selected) {
                        isSelected = isSelected.concat([{ key: key, name: opt.name, value: opt.value }]);
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                var selectedOptionName = isSelected.length ? isSelected[0].name : null;
                var selectedOptionKey = isSelected.length ? isSelected[0].key : null;
                var selectedOptionvalue = isSelected.length ? isSelected[0].value : null;
                // Create the fake element
                var fakeElement = "<div class=\"jquery-select-step-element\">\n                  <div class=\"decrementStep\">" + decrementLabel + "</div>\n                  <div class=\"selectStepValue\" data-key=\"" + selectedOptionKey + "\" data-value=\"" + selectedOptionvalue + "\">\n                    " + selectedOptionName + "\n                  </div>\n                  <div class=\"incrementStep\">" + incrementLabel + "</div>\n                </div>";
                // Wrap select to a div
                var parentElement = $(element)
                    .wrap("<div class=\"jquery-select-step\"></div>")
                    .parent();
                // Append the fake element
                parentElement.append(fakeElement);
                // Fire callback when finished
                callback(vars, options, parentElement);
            });
        }
        /*
         * Function to check if variable is function
         */
        function isFunction(functionToCheck) {
            var getType = {};
            return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
        }
        /*
         * Function to handle the increment and decrement of the plugins
         * it fire onChange event and change the select value
         */
        function handleChange(element, vars, options, type) {
            var selectStepValue = $(element).find(".selectStepValue"); // Get the element that show the value
            var key = parseInt($(selectStepValue).attr("data-key")); // Get current active key
            var onChange = vars.onChange; // Get user onChange event
            // Check if the key is not less than 0 or bigger than select options length
            if (type === "decrement" && key <= 0 || type === "increment" && key >= options.length - 1) {
                return;
            }
            // Get the new key
            var newKey = (type === "decrement" ? (key - 1) : (key + 1));
            var _a = options[newKey], name = _a.name, value = _a.value; // Get name and value of the new key
            // Change value
            selectStepValue.text(name);
            selectStepValue.attr("data-key", newKey);
            selectStepValue.attr("data-value", value);
            // Change select element selected options
            jQuery(element).find(".select-step option").removeAttr('selected');
            jQuery(element).find(".select-step option:eq(" + newKey + ")").attr('selected', true);
            // Fire onChange event
            if (onChange !== null && isFunction(onChange)) {
                onChange({
                    key: newKey,
                    name: name,
                    value: value
                });
            }
        }
        /*
         * Function to initialize the plugins
         */
        function init(element) {
            addFakeElements(element, function (vars, options, parentElm) {
                // Listen to change event
                $(parentElm).on("click", ".decrementStep", function () {
                    handleChange(parentElm, vars, options, "decrement");
                });
                $(parentElm).on("click", ".incrementStep", function () {
                    handleChange(parentElm, vars, options, "increment");
                });
            });
        }
        init(this);
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

CSS:

```
/* Do not change */

.select-step {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* You can change from here */

.jquery-select-step {
    display: inline-block;
}
.jquery-select-step-element {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 45px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.jquery-select-step-element > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.decrementStep, .incrementStep {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fcfcfc, #eee);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#fcfcfc, #eee);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.incrementStep {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a combination of `setTimeout` and `setInterval` assigned to variables with `mousedown` and `mouseup` event listeners you can start a frequency counter after a set time from mousedown, and then clear those timers on mouseup.

If you replace the last function in your js with this (from line 114). You can abbreviate the actions into functions to make it a little more DRY, they are left open here for explanation.

For android and ios the event listeners are `touchstart` and `touchend` respectively.

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/manoeuvres/hmjc949t/1/

```
/*
 * Function to initialize the plugins
 */
var timer1, freq1;

function init(element) {
    addFakeElements(element, function (vars, options, parentElm) {
        // Listen to change event
        $(parentElm).on({
          click: function () {
              handleChange(parentElm, vars, options, "increment");
          },
          'touchstart mousedown': function(){
            timer1 = setTimeout(function(){
                freq1 = setInterval(function(){
                handleChange(parentElm, vars, options, "increment");
              }, 300); // vary this to control speed
            },300); // vary this to control start delay
          },
          'touchend mouseup': function(){
            clearTimeout(timer1);
            clearInterval(freq1);
          }
        },".incrementStep");
        $(parentElm).on({
          click: function () {
              handleChange(parentElm, vars, options, "decrement");
          },
          'touchstart mousedown': function(){
            timer1 = setTimeout(function(){
                freq1 = setInterval(function(){
                handleChange(parentElm, vars, options, "decrement");
              }, 300); // vary this to control speed
            },300); // vary this to control start delay
          },
          'touchend mouseup': function(){
           clearTimeout(timer1);
           clearInterval(freq1);
          }
        },".decrementStep");
    });
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Just curious if you have any thoughts on this... on mobile (im testing on iphone in Safari), when you press and hold the +, it cycles through as it should, but also highlights some of the "weight" text ("oz." to be exact) and brings up the copy/paste options that are in iOs.  This would be annoying to the user, so wondering if you know of any way to prevent that from happening? Or is that just default browser behavior that can't be avoided?

Comment: sure no problem, just add `.selectStepValue { user-select: none; }` to your CSS. Should do the trick. Alternatively a 'handcranked' method is to cover the text with a transparent div.

Comment: FYI, I had to add "-webkit-user-select: none !important;" as well to make it work in iOS, but seems to be good now.  Thanks!